Doubt regrading $\int_0^\pi \frac{x^2\sin x}{(2x-\pi)(1+\cos^2x)} dx$
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{x^2\sin x}{(2x-\pi)(1+\cos^2(x))} dx   \tag{1}$$
Applying the property
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$
$\int_0^\pi \frac{(\pi-x)^2 \sin(\pi-x)}{(\pi-2x)(1+\cos^2(\pi-x))}$
$\int_0^\pi \frac{(-\pi^2-x^2+2\pi x)(\sin(x)}{(2x-\pi)(1+\cos^2(x))} = I\tag{2}$
Adding  $(1)$ and $(2)$
$\implies 2I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\pi\sin(x)}{(1+\cos^2(x))}$
Now it's a standard integral letting $\cos(x)$ as $t$ then solving it I get $I = \pi^2/4$
Now my doubt is that is it right to cancel $(2x-\pi)$ as in limit there is $\pi/2$ which makes it undefined at that point
or first of all I have to break limit at $\pi/2$ before applying the property?
and also the graph of the function leads to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ area about $\pi/2$, due to which integral should be undefined??

Your original integral is divergent.

I am new to integration , so how do I determine if an integral is convergent or divergent?

please edit your post using Latex properly, it's hard to read

Here's the improper integral definition. The integral can be written as two limits, one of them being $\lim_{u \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}\int_{u}^{\pi}\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{\left(2x-\pi\right)\left(1+\cos^{2}x\right)}dx$. With some tricky bounding, you can prove that a lower bound of the integrand is $\frac{x-\pi}{\pi\left(\pi-2x\right)}$, and thus $\int_{u}^{\pi}\frac{x-\pi}{\pi\left(\pi-2x\right)}dx$ goes to $\infty$ as $u \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+$. I'm sure you can fill in the rest of the proof.

Original integral is Improper Integral, It is ill-defined in the sense that your integral function is not defined on integral range. $\frac{x²\sin x}{(2x-π)(1+\cos²(x)}$ not defined at $π/2$.
Its like proving $2=3$ .
For example, $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$$
is ill-defined.
Notice it can be calculated BUT it won't follow basic integral identity like $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{x}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$$
You will get $\infty-\infty$ on right hand integrals.
You may want to look at Cauchy principal value

The integral the OP is asking about diverges, but not because the integrand is undefined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$. It's because there's a non-integrable singularity there, and it takes a bit of work to show that. As an example, $\ln x$ is undefined at $x = 0$ yet $\int_{0}^{1}\ln xdx$ converges despite the vertical asymptote.

You can write the integral as
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x^2\sin x}{(2x-\pi)(1+\cos^2(x)} dx
{
=
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{(x+\pi/2)^2\cos x}{2x(1+\sin^2(x)} dx
\\=
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{(x^2+\pi^2/4+\pi x)\cos x}{2x(1+\sin^2(x)} dx
\\=
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{(x^2+\pi^2/4)\cos x}{2x(1+\sin^2(x)} dx
\\+
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\pi \cos x}{2(1+\sin^2(x)} dx.
}
$$
The reason for the last equality is that the second integrand is continuous. The first integrand is odd and its principal value vanishes.
